# workaround for new Chrome fullscreen exit bug?

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen

Earlier when you used `history.pushState()` in FullSCreen mode of Chrome (FullScreen via JS, not via user pressing button) it did not exit it, now it does, is there a workaround for it?

```
document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen(window.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT); 
// boom! now we'r in da fullscreen!

window.history.pushState(0,0,0) // any args
// boom! now we'r not ='(
```